# Compare given cells of each row of two tables

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to update the last column of one data table with the last column of another data table. This is part of a bigger vba code. The first table spreads from A2 to column K and row "lastrpivot1". The second goes from A1001 to column K and row "lastrpivot2". Beginning with the first row of table 2 (row1001) i have to find the equivalent row in table 1 based on the values in cells A to E.

So cells A to E or frow 1001 have to be compared to cells A to E of row 2, then row 3, then row 4... until a match if found or until row "lastrpivot1". When a match is found, the value in K must return to the K value of row 1001. EX: if AtoE of row 1001 match row AtoE of row 65, then copu K65 to K1001. there shound not be more than 1 match from each table. and if there is no match there is nothing to return.

Then we start this all over for row 1002 (second row of second chart), then 1003, 1004... to lastrpivot2.

I do use vba but i do not know all the functions. this is probably why i cant figure this out.

Thnka you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cell `K1001`, try this:

`=IF((A1001&B1001&C1001&D1001&E1001)=(A1&B1&C1&D1&E1),K1,"")`

Then drag the formula down.

This compares the entire row 1001 to the entire row 1, which is what you're asking for.

If you intend to *find* the matching row like a VLOOKUP (you kind of imply this, but it is not clear that this is your intention) then you will need to use VBA to do this.

Something like (untested):

```
Sub MatchTables()
Dim tbl1 as Range, tbl2 as Range
Dim var1() as Variant, var2() as Variant, v as Variant
Dim r as Long, matchRow as Long
Set tbl1 = Range("A1:K500") '## Modify as needed
Set tbl2 = Range("A1001:K15001") '## Modify as needed

ReDim var1(1 to tbl1.Rows.Count)
ReDim var2(1 to tbl2.Rows.Count)

'## store the range values, conctaenated, in array variables:
For r = 1 to tbl1.Rows.Count
    var1(r) = tbl1(r,1) & tbl1(r,2) & tbl1(r,3) & tbl1(r,4) & tbl(r,5)
Next
For r = 1 to tbl2.Rows.Count
    var2(r) = tbl2(r,1) & tbl2(r,2) & tbl2(r,3) & tbl2(r,4) & tbl2(r,5)
Next

r = 0
For each v in Var2
    r = r+1
    '## Check to see if there is a  complete match:
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(v, var1, False)) Then
        matchRow = Application.Match(v, var1, False)
        '## If there is a match, return the value from column K in the first table:
        tbl2.Cells(r,11).Value = tbl1.Cells(matchRow,10).Value
    Else:
        tbl2.Cells(r,11).Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: not exactly. i need to compare row 1001 to row 2. if its not a match then compare it to row 3. then 4,5,6,(up to the variable last row) until theres a match. when it finds one it has to return K or if it doesnt then return nothing.  Theeeen this restarts with row 1002 then 1003 up to the last one (variabkle)

Comment: You need to do that in VBA. What if there are multiple matches? But a better solution would be to get usable data with identifiers that you can use to lookup/index. If that is not an option, you will have to learn how to use VBA. This is not a particularly complicated request, but it would be if you don't already know some VBA.  While someone here might be willing to do your homework for you, and write your code for you, I'm not.  I would suggest using the `AutoFilter` method, but that will maybe be problematic if your data is all in one sheet like you describe, and in the same columns.

Comment: yes this will be part of a vba code. i know how to use vbs but i dont master it. ive trying for 2 days and my coworkers are waiting for this. i did all the rest of my code but this part i just dont know how to do. can you at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please revise your original question and I can take a look at it.  Now that I think about it a little more, you could concatenate the values and store them in a one-dimensional array/Variant, then a simple `Match` function would suffice. That would actually be pretty easy.

Comment: Done. What i understand from this code it seems like it sould so the job, but unfortunately nothing happens. it just leaves everyting as is. like if there were no matches. for test purposes im actually using ecaxlty the same tables so each row should return a value.

Comment: i put "aaaaa" into cell E2 to see what happenes. i ran the code and it deleted what was in J of the forst ros of the second table. this was the equivalent row of the one i changed intable 1.

Comment: found the mistake! you referenced J instead of K so it appeared like nothing was happening. wow thats a bunch man. i spent hours on this  unable to come up with something. im defenitely gonna study this for next time. 
Thanks!